# Does IntelliJ IDEA Have Built-In Reverse Debugging Feature?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I guess the header is obvious , i really like to undo my debug process it will save lots time.
One of my coworker said to me that he did it once but he couldn't remember again how to do it.

Comment: You might also want to look into the Chronon Debugger: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/try-chronon-debugger-with-intellij-idea-13-1-eap/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not an undo operation in the usual sense, but you can drop the stack frame and re-enter same method again by calling `Run -> Drop Frame` menu item.